# Посчитать интеграл методом интегрирования по частям

Tags: математика

Признаю сразу - решаю все примеры чисто на интуиции,глубокого понимания нету.Не получается решить примеры неопределенных интегралов следующего вида :

> ∫e^2x*xdx
>
> ∫(7x+2)*cos3xdx

Проблема в том,что когда я ищу производную от ответа,то он не сравним с условием.

Мое решение
1-го  примера :

> 1. u = e^2x
> 2. dv = xdx
> 3. du = u'dx = (e^2x)'dx = 2 * e^2x dx

В 3 пункте ищу производную от u.

> 4.v =  ∫dv = ∫xdx = x^2/2 + C

Здесь ищу выражение,при нахождении производной которого,мы получим условие в интеграл - первообразную.

> 5. ∫udv = uv - ∫vdu
>
>    ∫udv = e^2x * x^2/2 -  ∫x^2/2 * 2 * e^2x dx

При попытке вычисления такого выражение получаю

> e^2x * x^2/2 - 2 * x^3/3 * 1/2 * e^2x/2

Где

> x^3/3 = первообразная от x^2/2
>   *1/2 = Если я буду искать производную от x^3/3,то 3 у меня сократятся,а 2 нужно вернуть опять в знаменатель.

Помогите пожалуйста)

Comment: Погодите,стоп.Я же не пытался до конца искать производную от ответа.Ответ то большой и делать проверку еще.

Comment: не угадал с тем, что под дифференциал вносить... и это не понятно, как получил: `e^2x * x^2/2 - 2 * x^3/3 * 1/2 * e^2x/2` ...

Comment: @Fat-Zer посмотрите в какие переменные что я заносил.Все вроде-бы сходится

Comment: @Sckoriy, а вот последний интеграл взял неправильно... да и он явно сложнее чем изначальный, так что повторюсь: *не угадал с тем, что под дифференциал вносить*

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что он по математике, а не по программированию.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> решаю все примеры чисто на интуиции

Именно так оно и происходит :) Интуиция + опыт. После сотни интегралов будете сразу видеть, что брать и как. В вашем случае нужно "сбрасывать" степени, убирая все x.

Примерно так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Забавно, когда за вопрос ставят плюс, а за ответ - минус :)